# Exterior polyurethane to apply outdoors in cold weather?

Tags: exterior, polyurethane, temperature

Is there some kind of polyurethane I can apply outdoors in 40 degree weather?  The one I looked at, Helmsman Spar Urethane, appears to require a minimum temperature of 50 degrees.

Comment: Think 50 is the common min temp for most outdoor products you apply.  Might be some special use products out there.

Comment: And , it may also say "temperatures below 50 are not expected for 24 Hours ( or more)" . You are unlikely to find any conventional coating without this warning .  Usually the resin does not cure after it warms following cold exposure, so unless you are a polymer chemist , i would follow the instructions.

Comment: I've done it successfully, but with serious marine-grade 2-part polyurethane, which is not similar to any consumer product (this stuff will trash your immune system if you use it wrong).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - So you mix two ingredients and use special safety equipment to protect eyes, mouth, nose, and skin?  And you get the two ingredients somewhere that I wouldn't have access to?  Sounds like a dead end for me, unfortunately.